# Spring autowiring fails with Ibatis

Tags: spring, autowired

I am new to Spring and trying to use @Autowire annotation for my DAOImpl class (@Repository) from Service layer (@Service)

Here is my code:

```
@Service
public class DefaultLocationService implements LocationService
{
@Autowired
@Qualifier("countryDao")
private CountryDAO countryDao; // This is an interface

public void setCountryDao(CountryDAO countryDao) {
    this.countryDao = countryDao;
}


// More code
}
```

And then I have CountryDaoImpl class (@Repository) which implements CountryDAO

```
@Repository("countryDao")
public class CountryDAOImpl extends InstrumentedSqlMapDaoTemplate implements CountryDAO {

@Autowired
public CountryDAOImpl(DaoManager daoManager) {
    super(daoManager);
}
// More code
}



public class InstrumentedSqlMapDaoTemplate extends SqlMapDaoTemplate
{

public InstrumentedSqlMapDaoTemplate(DaoManager daoManager)
{
    super(daoManager);
}
// More code
}
```

The problem happens with SqlMapDaoTemplate as it has a constructor with argument and therefore Spring can not instantiate a default constructor and fails. For that I autowired the constructor in my DAOImpl class but still no luck and it fails with this exception:

```
  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument  with
 index 0 of type [com.ibatis.dao.client.DaoManager]: : No matching bean
 of type [com.ibatis.dao.client.DaoManager] found for dependency:
 expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
 this dependency. Dependency ann otations: {}; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
 matching bean of t ype [com.ibatis.dao.client.DaoManager] found for
 dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
 candid ate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Can you guys please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks,
Troy

Comment: Can you post the code where is your DaoManager created?

Comment: Also post please your Spring context configuration. Are you using Java or XML config?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly What the message says. You are missing bean of type DaoManager. When countryDay bean is being created by Spring, it tries to use constructor `public CountryDAOImpl(DaoManager daoManager)`. But it also needs (according to your configuration) find the bean with type DaoManager.

Just annotate DaoManager class with `@Repository` annotation also.

Comment: DaoManager is an interface which Ibatis provides. If I am not wrong this can not be annotated with @Repository.
Sorry but this probably won't help.